# UnicodeEncodeError :'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x85' in position 102: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

i am trying to save array in a text file and I am getting a Unicode error

```
df_duplicate = df[df['is_duplicate'] == 1]
dfp_nonduplicate = df[df['is_duplicate'] == 0]

# Converting 2d array of q1 and q2 and flatten the array: like {{1,2},{3,4}} to {1,2,3,4}
p = np.dstack([df_duplicate["question1"], df_duplicate["question2"]]).flatten()
n = np.dstack([dfp_nonduplicate["question1"], dfp_nonduplicate["question2"]]).flatten()

print ("Number of data points in class 1 (duplicate pairs) :",len(p))
print ("Number of data points in class 0 (non duplicate pairs) :",len(n))

#Saving the np array into a text file
np.savetxt('train_p.txt', p, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s')
np.savetxt('train_n.txt', n, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s')`
```

I know I need to change it to utf-8 format but how to do with this particular code I cant understand.
Still a beginner in python

Comment: does `savetxt` have an `encoding` parameter?

Comment: no i don't think so

Comment: Why do you think that?  Did you check the docs?

Comment: tried adding utf-8 and unicode new error . " NameError: name 'Unicode' is not defined

Comment: Tried everything still same error, nothing i do is able to get over this problem please help.

Comment: I doubt if all that `dstack` code is relevant.  Instead it looks like there's a character in your dataframe that isn't writable, at least not with `utf-8`.  A sample of the dataframe might help; also the error traceback.  I'm not a unicode expert, the the '\x85' looks wrong.  That notation should be use for hexidecimals, which are '0...7abcdef', no '8' or '9'.

Comment: "tried adding utf-8 and unicode new error . " NameError: name 'Unicode' is not defined" This makes no sense at all, and suggests that you didn't understand how it was supposed to be done. We would have to see the code to fix it.

Comment: @hpaulj `8` and `9` are definitely hexadecimal digits. Sure you aren't thinking of octal? As a sanity check, there should be 16 digits, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, which I found by putting `np.savetxt` into a search engine:

```
numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='n', header='', footer='', comments='# ', encoding=None)
    Save an array to a text file.
```

So, yes, it does have an `encoding` parameter. That is where you specify the file encoding. So:

```
np.savetxt('train_p.txt', p, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s', encoding='utf-8')
```

**That said**: the character in question is a very strange one to have in your text. It would help to see where your data comes from.

Comment: yes this does solves the problems , data is from kaggle  https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs. Thanks for this help.